# При вопросе про python какие метки надо ставить?

Tags: обсуждение, метки

Есть такие метки:

[python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) и [python-3.x](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x)

Какие из них надо использовать и от каких можно отказаться?

Comment: @nomnoms12, ответы - в ответы.

Answer (score 10):

Главная метка — [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). Вешайте её всегда.

Но есть и более специфичные метки, например:

- [python-3.x](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x)
- [python-2.x](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x)
- [python-3.8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.8)
- [python-2.7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7)

Их стоит использовать, только если вопрос непосредственно связан с конкретной версией. При этом сохраняя основную метку [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python).
Лично я в своих вопросах использую две метки — [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [python-3.x](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x).

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется излишним навешивать до трёх схожих меток на вопрос, только потому что он про питон. Одной метки [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) было бы достаточно. В большинстве случаев из содержимого либо ясно о какой версии идёт речь, либо это не имеет значения.

Вряд ли есть какой-то смысл указывать специфичные метки вплоть до минорной версии Python. Они теперь выходят ежегодно, а вопросы и ответы на нашем сайте предназначены на более длительный срок (я надеюсь на это).

Что касаемо третьего или второго питона, то и тут особой разницы нет - ответы зачастую подходят к обеим версиям. Да и тем более Python 2 уже давно считается устаревшим, а летом этого года достигнет EOL.

Comment: _"Python 2 летом достигнет EOL"_ Уже [достиг](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/) же. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @nomnoms12, в самом деле, не летом, а осталось до в середины апреля подождать - https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/

Comment: И все  скрипты на 2-м кто-то перепишет?